# Trendnet TEW-624UB 300Mbps correct optimized driver

Tags: wireless

Got a Trendnet tew-624UB 300Mbps newer revision wifi usb dongle.
Works just fine!

On checking connection information on n etwork manager it shows up as a 150Mbps device using rtl8192cu as a driver.
This device is a 300Mbps wifi dongle.

The maximum TX strength is 80% and signal strength 100%...which is just fine!
But i have no range?!!
Checked with the router touching it and its still 80 %
On checking this device with win7 everything is 100% running @ 300Mbps........it catches 2 floors strong signal but not with ubuntu 12.04!
Simply put the "rtl8192cu " is a 150Mbps driver and not 300Mbps.

Is there a 300Mbps driver or an upgrade path for this device that i can use far away from my 300 Mbps router..... it works fine @ 150Mbps but with no range.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. My blog with other OS too... 
http://tuxstack.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/install-drivers-for-wifi-usb-adapters-trendnet-tew-624ub-tp-link-wn821n-asus-edimax-etc-on-linux/

Trendnet TEW624UB and Tp-link wn821n have the same chipset. There are many devices which have the same pathetic rtl8192cu wifi chipset.

Apparently, the driver from realtek website is unmaintained and shows up as a 150Mbps driver but is very buggy(already included in kernel). Thanks to Janez troha for maintaining the driver and making it installable for kernel 3.8, 3.10 and as he/she puts it 3.11++.
https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu

The rtl8192cu works 24/7 without glitches with the change Janez has made to the source.

You can check with iwconfig or network-manager applet to see the speed of data transfer, it will clearly show it is 300Mbps and NOT 150Mbps.

I hope realtek provides better support for linux.

Further linked to : [Installing Workaround RealTek Drivers for EdiMAX, but getting error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290452/installing-workaround-realtek-drivers-for-edimax-but-getting-error)
&&
[Installing Workaround RealTek Drivers for EdiMAX, but getting error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290452/installing-workaround-realtek-drivers-for-edimax-but-getting-error)

Answer (score 0):

I use TEW-625BRP, also rated at 300 mbps.
I too thought that the rtl8192cu was only 150 mbps,
but I downloaded the driver and softare from Realtek website.
now BOTH realtek software and Windows networking shows 300 mbps