# Installing Workaround RealTek Drivers for EdiMAX, but getting error

Tags: wireless, realtek

```
vitt@vitt-System-Product-Name:~/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105$ sudo sh install.sh
[sudo] password for vitt: 
##################################################
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
Decompress the driver source tar ball:
    rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105.tar.gz
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/clean
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/ieee80211.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_ht.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/sdio_osintf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_ioctl.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_event.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_rf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192d_rf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_sreset.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192d_hal.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/recv_osdep.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_recv.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_cmd.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/byteorder/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/byteorder/generic.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/byteorder/little_endian.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/byteorder/swabb.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/byteorder/swab.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/byteorder/big_endian.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/pci_osintf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/sdio_ops.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192CPhyReg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/osdep_service.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/usb_osintf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_spec.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/pci_hal.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192CPhyCfg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_pwrctrl.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192d_cmd.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192DETestHWImg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_version.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/ethernet.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_br_ext.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_qos.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_p2p.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192d_xmit.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/xmit_osdep.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_mp_ioctl.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_xmit.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192d_spec.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/usb_hal.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/pci_ops.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_mp.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192CEHWImg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/mlme_osdep.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/h2clbk.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/sdio_ops_xp.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/usb_vendor_req.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_eeprom.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/farray.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192DPhyCfg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/ioctl_cfg80211.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192d_dm.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/if_ether.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/drv_types_ce.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_security.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_ioctl_rtl.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192DUHWImg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192CUHWImg_wowlan.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192d_led.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_led.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/wlan_bssdef.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_mlme_ext.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192DPhyReg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/wifi.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192d_recv.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_event.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192DEHWImg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192CUHWImg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/nic_spec.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/osdep_intf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/sdio_ops_ce.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/sdio_ops_linux.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/circ_buf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_byteorder.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_xmit.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192DUHWImg_wowlan.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_ioctl_set.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_recv.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_dm.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_mlme.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/mp_custom_oid.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/ip.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_ioctl_query.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/hal_init.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/drv_conf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192DUTestHWImg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/drv_types_linux.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/autoconf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/osdep_ce_service.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_efuse.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_cmd.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/sdio_hal.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_io.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_led.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/ieee80211_ext.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/cmd_osdep.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/drv_types.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/sta_info.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_iol.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/usb_ops.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_hal.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_debug.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/drv_types_xp.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_rf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_android.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/basic_types.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_mp_phy_regdef.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_rf.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_mlme.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_eeprom.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_io.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_br_ext.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/.tmp_rtw_wlan_util.o
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_mp_ioctl.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_iol.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_p2p.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_ioctl_set.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_debug.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_xmit.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_ieee80211.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_cmd.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_pwrctrl.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_security.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_ioctl_query.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_ioctl_rtl.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_sta_mgt.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_wlan_util.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_mp.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/.rtw_wlan_util.o.d
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/efuse/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_recv.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/Makefile
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/ifcfg-wlan0
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/wlan0dhcp
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/osdep_service.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/pci_intf.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/sdio_intf.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/Kconfig
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_sreset.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_dm.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_hal_init.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_cmd.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_phycfg.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_xmit.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_ops_ce.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_led.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/Hal8192CUHWImg.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_halinit.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/Hal8192CUHWImg_wowlan.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_ops_linux.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_ops_xp.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_recv.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_rxdesc.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_rf6052.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_mp.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/hal_init.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
install.sh: 38: [: unexpected operator
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm .tmp_versions -fr ; rm Module.symvers -fr
rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd hal/rtl8192c/usb ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd hal/rtl8192c ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
install.sh: 48: [: unexpected operator
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build M=/home/vitt/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/vitt/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/vitt/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_cmd.c:23:0:
/home/vitt/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘thread_enter’:
/home/vitt/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/osdep_service.h:575:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘daemonize’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
In file included from /home/vitt/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/drv_types.h:69:0,
                 from /home/vitt/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_cmd.c:24:
/home/vitt/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_recv.h: In function ‘rxmem_to_recvframe’:
/home/vitt/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_recv.h:626:30: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/vitt/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_recv.h:626:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/vitt/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/vitt/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

The driver code from Realtek uses some functions (`kernel_thread()` and `daemonize()`) that have been removed from newer kernels. Fortunately, a helpful person on Github has ported the Realtek driver to the new APIs that accomplish the same thing in 3.8+ kernels.

The port is available at: https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu

To install the ported driver (assuming you have git, build-essential and linux-headers-generic already), do:

```
git clone https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu.git
cd rt8192cu
make
sudo make install
```

Then, to unload the built-in driver that doesn't work (rtl8192cu) and load your new driver (8192cu):

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8192cu
sudo modprobe 8192cu
```

To keep using your new driver instead of the built-in one, add this to the end of `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist rtl8192cu
```

Comment: Did you ever know that you're my hero? You're everything I wish I could be. I could fly higher than an eagle, 'cause you are the wind beneath my wings. Seriously. I've been trying to get my usb wifi adapter recognized by Debian Wheezy for hours, and this was the trick.

Comment: Worked for me!!!

Comment: what to do next after performing above steps ?

Comment: @BhartiLadumor After loading your new driver with `modprobe`, make sure the wifi device is attached to the computer, and configure it to connect to wifi like any other wifi device on your distro. On Ubuntu 20.04 (if that kernel is still compatible), you would go to the upper right corner and hopefully see the wifi device in that main system menu, where you can click on it and pick a network.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this error while trying to compile the rtl8192cu driver under Linux 3.8.X:

I have patched the osdep_service.h file.

I have added this line:

```
void daemonize(char *, char *);
```

just before these lines:

```
inline static void thread_enter(void *context)
{
#ifdef PLATFORM_LINUX
    //struct net_device *pnetdev = (struct net_device *)context;
    //daemonize("%s", pnetdev->name);
    daemonize("%s", "RTKTHREAD");
    allow_signal(SIGTERM);
#endif
}
```

Hope that helps.

David

Comment: I made this patch, and successfully built the module, but it refuses to modprobe in because of (surprise, surprise) "unknown symbol daemonize (err 0)" and, more surprisingly, "unknown symbol kernel_thread (err 0)". This driver needs to be rewritten to use kthread_create.

Answer (score 2):

I just got a D-Link DWA-131 manufactured on May 2013. I similarly see the the same  logs in dmesg that existed before the driver install:

```
[188290.668104] usb 1-2.1.4: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
[188290.668107] usb 1-2.1.4: Manufacturer: Realtek
[188290.668110] usb 1-2.1.4: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
```

I use the following kernel:

Linux 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

I fixed the problem with the instructions here: http://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=3515.0

basically -

```
echo "2001 330D" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id
```

Answer (score 0):

That install script requires bash, not sh. That will solve your error messages like `install.sh: 48: [: unexpected operator`.

However, I am also unable to compile this package on Ubuntu 13.04, and I think it's because the supplied kernel is too new for Realtek's sources.  I welcome any advice for workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same error.
Following this thread fixed it for me :

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=135505#p726075

This thread in turn references ubuntuforums thread (but right now the site is down so can't confirm that).

Ringtail:~$ uname -a
Linux Ringtail 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:19:42 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. What if the Mint forum goes down and disappears, too?? ;-)