# unable to install ew-7811un

Tags: wireless

```
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/jonjon/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/jonjon/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

I was trying to install a driver for Edimax ew-7811un.
I was following this instructions: http://www.r-statistics.com/2011/11/edimax-ew-7811un-usb-wireless-connecting-to-a-network-on-ubuntu-11-10/
This what I get when i try to run the install.sh

Any idea?

Comment: refer here [http://askubuntu.com/questions/509498/is-there-a-standard-wifi-driver](http://askubuntu.com/questions/509498/is-there-a-standard-wifi-driver-for-the-edimax-ew-7811un)

Comment: I believe `rtl8192cu` is included by default in all recent Ubuntu versions. Do you have some other problem with it?

Comment: answer here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/290452/installing-workaround-realtek-drivers-for-edimax-but-getting-error